# I'm having trouble referencing my ids and classes from the .css file to the .html file

Tags: html, css

```css
h1 {
    background-color: chocolate
}
img {margin: 20px
}
#testing { color: white; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Zoo Animals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CODECA/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testing">
        <h1>All Animals Are Brethren</h1>
        <p>Play With a Bear Today</p>
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/46175/bear-brown-bear-animal-teddy-bear-46175.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="450px
            " alt="cookie">
    </div>
    <h2 class="bleak">
        <p>what else</p>
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

When I make an ID in my html file, it's successful. I get no error messages in the terminal.  But when I input `#id1 {color} white` into the .css file, nothing happens.

I've tried reinstalling the program and trying a different program altogether, so I think it might be something I'm doing wrong.

Every time I try and paste the code in the question, it says my formatting is wrong. I'm really new to coding, but I'm really trying to learn too; I was doing well with everything else until this one hiccup.

I've attached an image that shows the html doc and css side by side. I hope this is clear.

[Snapshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9s85.jpg)

Comment: you have to write it like this `#id1 {color: white;}`

Comment: Can you please share some of your code?

Comment: my html line is like ' <div id="testing" ' Then in my .css file, my coding is ' #testing {background-color: black} But when I type in the mentioned code in .css, my '#testing' is red<<<Is that clear???

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should be

```
    #id1 {color: white};
```

or

```
   .className {color: white};
```

Note that if you are using this specific style on a white background your text is going to disappear.

Comment: my html line is like ' <div id="testing" ' Then in my .css file, my coding is ' #testing {background-color: black} But when I type in the mentioned code in .css, my '#testing' is red<<<Is that clear???

Comment: Are you pulling your .css file into the .html correctly?

Comment: I think I was, because other factors of the css work; ie: h1 {color-black} : But I have posted a snapshot of what the code looks like.

Comment: Can you post it so the text is actually wrapping? and maybe an image of what you are seeing? Or a jsfiddle?